# Java list value replacing

Tags: java, list

If I was to have a java list with five elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 that all had int number values. How can I get the sum of the a combination of the elements in the place of the elements I combined

The packages I am using are as follows:

```
java.util.ArrayList  
java.util.LinkedList  
java.util.Vector  
java.util.Stack  
java.util.iterator
```

Example

```
myList(o) = 1  
myList(1) = 2  
myList(2) = 3  
myList(3) = 4  
myList(4) = 5
```

I combine elements 1-3

```
myList(0) = 1
myList(1) = 9  //sum of elements 2,3,4, indexed as 1-3
myList(2) = 5
```

What I am asking is instead of automatically adding a new value (in this case 9) to the END of a list to a certain place.

Comment: can you show some code to better explain what you are doing?

Comment: its very hard to understand the question. can you show codes instead?

Comment: So you'd have a function such as `void combine(List<Integer> val)` or something?

Answer (score 3):

Simply rebuild the list and add elements within your range:

```
public static List<Integer> combine(List<Integer> list, int start, int end) {
    ArrayList<Integer> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        //If not in combine range, simply add the element to the new list
        if (i < start || i > end) {
            lst2.add(list.get(i));
        } else {
            //Otherwise, add element to combine sum, and add to list when we are done
            sum += list.get(i);
            if (i == end) {
                lst2.add(sum);
            }
        }
    }
    return lst2;
}
```

From your example it seems that you want your range to be *inclusive* on both ends. If not (and end index should be exclusive), simply change `i > end` to `i >= end` and `i == end` to `i == end - 1`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `List.add(int index, Integer element)` overload.  Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList() {{
       add(1); 
       add(2);
       add(3);
       add(4);
       add(5);
    }};

    sumSubList(myList, 1, 3);
    System.out.println(myList);
}

public static void sumSubList(List<Integer> list, int start, int end) {
    // Check to that start and end indices are within the bounds of the list
    if ((start > end) ||
        (start < 0) ||
        (end > list.size() - 1))
        return;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum += list.get(start);
        // Remove this element after it's been added to the sum
        list.remove(start); 
    } 
    // Add the sum at the starting point
    list.add(start, sum);
}
```

Results:

```
[1, 9, 5]
```